# How to test for hexidecimal output on serial port in python

Tags: python, serial-port, hex

When i send a command over serial, the slave responds with a hexidecimal sequence, i.e.:

this series:

```
05 06 40 00 02 05 F6 5C
```

gives me

```
05 07 40 05 02 05 71 37 FF
```

The response always ends with the FF byte. So i want to read the bytes into a buffer untill i encounter FF. Than the buffer should be printed and the function should return.

```
import serial

s_port = 'COM1'
b_rate = 2400

#method for reading incoming bytes on serial
def read_serial(ser):
    buf = ''
    while True:
        inp = ser.read(size=1) #read a byte
        print inp.encode("hex") #gives me the correct bytes, each on a newline
        buf = buf + inp #accumalate the response
        if 0xff == inp.encode("hex"): #if the incoming byte is 0xff
            print inp.encode("hex") # never here
            break
    return buf   

#open serial
ser = serial.Serial(
    port=s_port,
    baudrate=b_rate,
    timeout=0.1
)

while True:

    command = '\x05\x06\x40\x00\x02\x05\xF6\x5C' #should come from user input
    print "TX: "
    ser.write(command)
    rx = read_serial(ser)
    print "RX: " + str(rx)
```

gives me:

```
TX: 
05
07
40
05
02
05
71
37
ff
```

Why is the condition never met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're comparing apples and oranges.  `inp.encode("hex")` returns a string.  Let's say you read the letter `"A"`.  `"A".encode("hex")` returns the string `"41"` and `0x41 != "41"`.  You should either do:

```
if '\xff' == inp:
    ....
```

Or, convert `inp` into a number using `ord()`:

```
if 0xff == ord(inp):
    ....
```

Then it should work as expected.

Comment: the upper one works for me, the lower one complains that ord needs a character string and it received a string of length 0

Comment: That sounds like `inp` can be an empty string then (`''`)... is that expected?  If so, the string match (the first option) is probably better.  You may want to do something special in that case though.  I assume you're using pyserial, and an empty string usually means that the operation timed out.

Comment: Yes, strings match the answer better than only numbers. Thanks for your input